# .Net Web Service call from php

Tags: .net, php, web-services

How can I call a .Net Web Service from within php. Are there any useful libraries for php 4/5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/soap) installed then I would recommend [nuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with karim79. nuSoap is an excellent, easy to use library.

Once installed, try something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('libs/nusoap.php'); 
$wsdl="http://www.mydomain.com/mywebservice.wsdl";
$client=new soapclient($wsdl, 'wsdl');
$param=array('myparam1'=>'myval1', 'myparam2'=>'myval2'); 
echo $client->call('mymethodname', $param);
?>
```

Note that webservices are platform independent by definition, so the fact that the service is written in .NET is not relevant.